# Add new column to polars DataFrame

Tags: python-polars

Being a new user to polars coming from pandas, I have searched polars GitHub pages, user guide, stackoverflow and discord channel on how to add a new column to a polars dataframe.
I have only found polars examples on how to add new columns based on existing ones.

How should the following pandas example be converted to polars syntax?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'existing_column': [1, 2, 3]})

df['new_column'] = "some text"
```

With expected content of final dataframe:

| existing_column | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | some_text |
| 2 | some_text |
| 3 | some_text |

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use `with_columns` and `pl.lit` to add a new column with Polars that is a constant and not based on existing columns.

You can use it for both text and numbers.

Here is an example:

```
df.with_columns(
    new_column = pl.lit('some_text')
)
```

The advantage of Polars is that all new columns added and all columns transformed within the same `with_columns` will be calculated in parallel.

Comment: Just a note after a good 20 min of time wasting, if you have a column name you can just do:
df.with_columns(**{col_name_var: pl.lit('some_text')})

Which will be translated to 

df.with_columns(ACTUALVALUEOFcol_name_var =  pl.lit('some_text'))